# How to get 32 bit version of libraries on Ubuntu 64 bit?

Tags: compiling, 32-bit, libraries, g++

I'm trying to compile a program which uses Google's V8 library (which is 32 bit). Therefore any library I use within my program also has to be 32 bit. Where can I download the 32 bit version of libraries on Ubuntu 64 bit? More specifically, I'm looking for the libnotify 32 bit version.

This is the errors I am getting right now:

```
g++ -o shell -m32 shell.o -L../v8 -lv8 -lpthread `pkg-config --libs libnotify glib-2.0`
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../libnotify.so when searching for -lnotify
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../libnotify.a when searching for -lnotify
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libnotify.so when searching for -lnotify
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libnotify.a when searching for -lnotify
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnotify
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks!

Comment: check the answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/20355/3940)

Comment: turns out it's now possible to compile V8 for 64bit "scons arch=4"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install 32bit libraries on a 64bit machine by installing the [ia32-libs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ia32-libs) package:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Can you think of any problems that installing ia32-libs on a 64-bit system would cause or is doing this harmless?

Comment: @djangofan It's harmless, it's designed for this specific issue.

Comment: The package doesn't exist anymore in Ubuntu 20.04 :(

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package