# What happened to the ia32-libs package?

Tags: multiarch

The `ia32-libs` package is no longer present in Ubuntu 12.04 repositories for a 64bit system.
Are there any available replacement packages available for download?

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/359156/how-do-you-run-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu/359184#359184

Comment: +1, was just going to ask exactly the same question. SO has really great question suggestions!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The ia32-libs package was a hack to get 32-bit packages installed on a 64-bit installation. Since Ubuntu version 11.10 (Oneiric), [Multi Arch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) has been added. One of the objectives for it is removing the `ia32-libs` package. Instead, you have to install the 32-bit libraries of a package with:

```
sudo apt-get install package-name:i386
```

You don't have to worry about this for packages in the standard repositories (e.g. the `wine` package). For external software, it's a bit more difficult because you have to find the dependencies manually. In that case, use your favorite search engine to find which libraries you need.

It seems that ia32-libs still exist, but merely as a convenience package to include common 32-bit libraries. This package now uses Multi Arch to install the 32-bit packages correctly.

Comment: Well, how is one suppose to find all the dependencies and first install :i386 of those ?

Comment: @wingman Run `ldd`, passing a path to the binary as argument. If the output contains a line like `libz.so.1 => not found`, then you need to find `libz.so.1`. You can use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ or `apt-file search` to find the package containing that file. In the example I gave, you need to install `zlib1g:i386`.

Comment: i am in a computer with ubuntu 10.10. following some tutorial on android development i have to install the ia32-libs. your answer talk about 11.10, but for this computer? what i have to do?

Comment: @nkint 10.10 is not supported anymore. If you want to proceed, you need to change your [package sources](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/6969). In 10.10 you need to install ia32-libs. But even then there is no guarantee that the android SDK works with that.

Comment: ➜  ~  sudo apt-get install package-name:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package package-name

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli You need to replace `package-name` by the actual name. Use `ldd` to figure out, see the second comment above.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Thanks so much for the `apt-file` tip. I really wonder why this is not installed by default. Had to install it manually. All those past years, I was using the 'Files' branch at http://pkgs.org to find the whereabouts of a particular library file.

Comment: You will need the libc6-x32, to get the 32 bit loader which ldd uses to supply the list of called 32 bit libraries.  Without that loader (/libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2), ldd will simply give up and falsely claim that the 32 bit executable is not an executable. (bug 1616609).

Answer (score 46):

## Ubuntu 13.10

### What happened?

The `ia32-libs` package has been completely replaced by `lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`. This should not be a problem because its functionality is still there, just in other packages. However, we do not live in an ideal world where everyone maintains their packages and all software is FLOSS, so some packages still depend on the ia32-libs.

### How can I install package *x* that depends on ia32-libs

There are 2 ways:

1. You can repackage it manually so it does not depend on the `ia32-libs` anymore. (preferred)
2. You can install ia32-libs from the Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) repository (**not preferred at all!, only if first method does not work**)

#### 1. Repackage old packages

I will use the citrix receiver as an example, but you can use this method for any .deb package:

First, download the citrix receiver .deb package from their website and make a temporary directory do do the hacking in.

```
mkdir ica_temp
```

Extract the package

```
dpkg-deb -x icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb ica_temp
dpkg-deb --control icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb ica_temp/DEBIAN
```

Open the file in gedit (or your favorite editor)

```
sudo -H gedit ica_temp/DEBIAN/control
```

Find the line that starts with `Depends:...`. remove `ia32-libs` and add `lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`

Rebuild the modified package

```
dpkg -b ica_temp icaclient-modified.deb
```

And install it

```
sudo dpkg -i icaclient-modified.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

*Installing the citrix receiver requires some hacking too. You can find the full installation instructions on [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo)*

You can do this with any old .deb package that still depends on ia32-libs.

#### 2. Install ia32-libs from raring repository

**Please note that is it very bad practice to install old packages!** Sadly, for some binary installers, you do not have any other choice.

You can download the ia32-libs package from [the raring repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/ia32-libs/download).
Download it and install it manually, then the dependencies should be resolved.

Comment: What is "FOS"?  I tried: http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/FOS

Comment: @Elipticalview "Free and Open Source". Changed it to FLOSS (Free/Libre and open source software), which is more common.

Comment: "Repackage old packages" works mostly for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial - you just need to add a few adaptions to the package-names, usually adding the ":i386"-namespace to the end of the package-names. Some of the packages have different names too, like libbz2-1.0:i386

Answer (score 6):

I read that you are supposed to install the `ia32-libs-multiarch` package instead.
However it didn't work for me and I get this error

```
ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed.
```

The solution which worked for me was to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 gcc-4.6-base:i386 libstdc++5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: Works for elementary OS luna also

Answer (score 4):

If you get that error, try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try it again:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I just did a fresh install of 12.04, that package is still available in the repositories.
In fact, I got that error myself before I ran update. Afterwards, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this specific use case was replaced with the packages "lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32asound2", which is probably a more specific and useful answer than saying "you can use multi-arch".

Comment: What? There's no specific use case in this question.

Comment: @gertvdijk: The package itself represents a limited use case; for a more general purpose you can multi-arch, but for people who were using this one specific package before, it seems to have been replaced with "lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32asound2", which you can install without having to use multi-arch: that covers the same use cases as the previous package. In essence, I found these answers unhelpful, as multi-arch was overkill for the reason that ia32-libs existed, was surprised there wasn't a more direct drop-in replacement, and wasn't disappointed when I researched this further.

Comment: This was the simplest answer that solved a similar problem for me.
Even though the libs indicated doesn't seem to have anything to do
with starting up a general binary it did work.

Answer (score -2):

I installed the ia32-libs like this (I run Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail on a 64 bit machine):

Check own architecture:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
```

Check if a foreign architecture is installed:

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

Depending on the results of the two commands above, the following three commands might work (took a long time to process in my case):

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: I get: `Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
`