# Couldn't find package ia32-libs

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the ia32-libs package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package)

I am not able to install these libraries. Where should i download these from and how to install them?

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package?rq=1 . Also a Possible Duplicate.

Comment: The command that you've used worked for me just now.  What Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the 32 bit version of Ubuntu, you don't need nor will you find an ia32-libs package. That's only required for the 64 bit version of Ubuntu.

To install 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit Ubuntu system,

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```