# Couldn't find package ia32-libs

Tags: apt, 64-bit, android, software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the ia32-libs package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package)

I want to install some Android plugins in Eclipse on my 64bit Ubuntu, but since android is 32bit compatible, I also have to install `ia-32-libs`. Unfortunately, trying to install it gives the following error:

```
Couldn't find package ia32-libs
```

How should I install this package?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the terminal:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-cache search ia32

there you will see how the package is named. ia32-libs is a transitional package. There is another one called ia32-libs-multiarch

so you can try to install them:

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch