# Skype installation fails, cannot install ia32-libs

Tags: software-center, 64-bit, skype

When I try to install it from the Software Center, it displays an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype: Depends: skype-bin but it is a virtual package
```

Running `sudo apt-get install Skype` gives the same error.

When I download it from the official website, the .deb file opens in Software Center and displays "Cannot install 'ia32-libs'" and doesn't even show the install button.

Please help. How can I install Skype?

Answer (score 1):

Try install `ia32-libs` with this: [ia32-libs installation askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package).
Then try install Skype again.

Comment: I've tried but didn'nt work...
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Type from terminal `sudo apt-get install skype-bin`, this should get you the latest version of Skype from the repositories

The other option is to download the package from skype official website.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar kind of problem and this seemed to do the trick immediately:
http://www.gmjjavadesigns.com/content/ubuntu-1304-skype-wont-load-because-error-finding-libglso1

Or simply in terminal:

- `gksu gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf`
- Add line:
- `/usr/lib32`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
- `sudo ldconfig -v`
- Run Skype