# Valve's Steam on Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, steam

I've tried installing Steam from [Valve's website](http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb) , although I had a persistent error when trying to start `steam`:

```
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1352224866_client)
```

I've so far tried the [another askubuntu.com solved question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213864/installing-breakpad-exception-handler-for-appidsteam-while-trying-to-run-ste) with installing ia32-libs, although this didn't work. I'm pretty not sure what to do next to fix this problem.

Comment: that terminal output you see is not an error. If you give it some more time, you can see steam showing up.

Comment: I'm pretty not sure about the amount of time to be given. I've "left it to open" for quite a few hours and don't think that it will. Maybe there's some kind of error log out there?

Comment: I don't have any other input regarding this. Installing ia32-libs was enough for me to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, updated Steam works without problems, guess this can be closed.