# Programs not opening?

Tags: 14.04

I'm using 14.04, and I've recently installed Steam, Deluge, and Chromium, but none of them actually WORK. When I click on them to open, all I get is a blank header bar which goes away the instant I click on another window, and yet the program is still open. What gives?

Comment: What happens when you run one of these from the command line?

Comment: I've run all three through Terminal. Steam just lists something about "breakpads" and the blank header opens again. Deluge shows a blank header without any sort of code. Chromium does the same.

Comment: how did you install these programs?

Comment: I installed them using the Software Center that came with 14.04.

Comment: try this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/213864/installing-breakpad-exception-handler-for-appidsteam-while-trying-to-run-ste)

Comment: Letizia, it tells me:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate

Comment: Okay, the problem appears to have resolved itself. Deluge and Steam are working just fine, and Chromium is slow to start but works.