# Can adobe reader run from 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: adobe-reader

I installed it but when I try to run it nothing shows.

On Adobe's requirements for Ubuntu page it says: "32-bit Intel® Pentium® processor or equivalent"

Can I infer from it that adobe reader doesn't run on 64-bit processors in Ubuntu?

Comment: You're reading it wrong, you need a 32-bit as minimum to run it. 64-bit processors can handle 32-bit instructions as well as 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Reader can run on 64-bit Ubuntu, but it's a 32-bit program, so you need to install the 32-bit version of the libraries it depends on.  Since 12.04 Ubuntu uses the [Multi Arch system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package) to install dependencies like this.

First, install the 32-bit version of Adobe Reader's dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Now we can install the 32-bit Acrobat Reader package downloaded from [Adobe's Website](http://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions/):

```
sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to run this command to get Adobe Reader to actually work:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work on Ubuntu 12.04 or later.  See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package) for an explanation why.