# flux on 13.04 unable to set preferences

Tags: 13.04, python

I installed flux from the Kilian PPA, which installs fine. i run the app and the icon displays in the tray.

however, when i try to set my preferences, the menu does not ever appear. i found the flux log in `/tmp` and am hoping someone here can decipher it for me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py", line 381, in <module>
    app = Fluxgui()

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.settings.zipcode, self.settings.color)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py", line 48, in start_xflux
    self.xflux = pexpect.spawn("/usr/bin/xflux", args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 430, in __init__
    self._spawn (command, args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 560, in _spawn
    os.execv(self.command, self.args)

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

It is missing ia32-libs dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

will do the trick.

The problem is that the binary file `/usr/bin/xflux` is is expected to run with 32 bits libs, so it doesn't work in a 64 bits Ubuntu without the explicit inclusion of the ia32-libs package.

Comment: Upvoted since this clued me in to the problem.  However, this no longer works.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Just got this error in Ubuntu 13.10, where `ia32-libs` is no longer available.  It appears the solution today is to either manually repackage fluxgui with the new 32-bit packages, or install ia32-libs from the 13.04 repository (not recommended).  See: https://askubuntu.com/a/394156/50450.

I ended up just grabbing the pre-built 64-bit CLI daemon from http://justgetflux.com/linux.html which worked out of the box (Xbuntu 13.10).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be quite enough information here, but can you do:

```
ls /usr/bin/xflux
```

From the traceback, I assume that file is missing. If it is, run

```
sudo updatedb && locate xflux
```

if it isn't found, remove/reinstall fluxgui, if it is, symbolic link it to /usr/bin/xflux with ln -s

If that file DOES exist, then I am not sure my friend.