# How to install ia32-libs?

Tags: 64-bit

Today I updated from 13.04 to 13.10. Then `sudo apt-get autoremove` removed all 32bit packages.

How to get them back? How do I install ia32-libs again?

This is what I get if I try to install them back :

```
output$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: More relevant question: [What happened to the ia32-libs package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package)

Comment: Guys, it may not be a duplicate. The simple reason being ia32 multiarch behaviour has changed in Ubuntu 13.10 compared to earlier versions. All old packages which require ia32libs to install example: citrix, codewavers, teamviewer, google earth and others cannot be installed in 13.10. The actual answer is ia32-libs is no more available in 13.10

Comment: @Ubuntuser Is it a duplicate, since the answers would be the same

Comment: not duplicate since none actually show you how to install `ia32-libs` for programs built from source such as my drivers.  wonder if it's time to check out that mint distro...

Comment: supposedly this works http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: Yeah.. so no answer. If you run a package that depends on ia32-libs, then in the newer version of Ubuntu you are screwed.. lol.. great answer... I found a work around here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/366438/how-to-install-google-earth-64bit-in-ubuntu-13-10-ia32-libs-dependency-error