# install IRAF on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, 32-bit

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit. Now I want to install programme IRAF, which is running on 32 bit system. And I can not install ia32-libs.

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs   this is not working

What to do, so the programme will work?
I tried so many different things, but nothing works...
Do I have to install Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit or is there any other sulution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to the ia32-libs package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package)

Answer (score 3):

Just install the 64-bit version of IRAF:

```
% mkdir iraf.v2161 
% cd iraf.v2161
% wget ftp://iraf.noao.edu/iraf/v216/iraf.lnux.x86_64.tar.gz
% tar zxf iraf.lnux.x86_64.tar.gz
% ./install                         # accept prompt defaults
% iraf                              # to start IRAF in an XGterm
```

See http://iraf.net for more details

Comment: I do not find the file in the ftp repo you are linking to. In fact, no files with names starting with "iraf".

Comment: Oh - seems like the currently correct link is: 
ftp://iraf.noao.edu/iraf/v216/PCIX/iraf.lnux.x86_64.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

You can get statically linked binaries from

```
ftp://iraf.noao.edu/pub/fitz/xgterm.STATIC
ftp://iraf.noao.edu/pub/fitz/ximtool.STATIC
```

The ia32-libs aren't needed for IRAF so long as you're using the 64-bit system

Answer (score 0):

I installed IRAF on Ubuntu 16 in a very elegant way by mean of Miniconda:

https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_unix

And then with:

https://anaconda.org/pkgw/iraf

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 and later, it is a simple

```
$ apt install iraf
```

to get IRAF.