# Ubuntu 13.10 x64 SteamCMD

Tags: 64-bit

I'm guessing that this question may of been asked before; however, I'm having trouble finding an answer.

I'm currently reviewing dependencies for all the Game server scripts I have written (http://danielgibbs.co.uk/scripts). There has been a big change with 13.10 with regards to 32-bit software vs. 64-bit versions of Ubuntu.

Previously you would install `ia32-libs` and SteamCMD would work. However, this is now deprecated, and I am having difficulty getting SteamCMD working.

Does anyone know the best way to get SteamCMD up and running on a 64-bit system without needing `ia32-libs`?

Comment: might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package

Comment: I saw that one. However I don't know which packages SteamCMD require for me to add the :i386 to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the Answer. You only require one extra dependency for it to work on Ubuntu x64.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

Tested this on the following distros:

Ubuntu 12.04 x64
Ubuntu 13.10 x64
Debian 6 "Squeeze" x64
Debian 7 "Wheezy" x64

Bonus info for CentOS 6 x64 users. Use the following to get SteamCMD working.

```
yum install glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in some cases caused by messed up libGL libraries.  Clean install or not.
Here is how I fixed it.

1. I got rid of all remnants of the drivers downloaded from nVidia (the latest one has a tendency of messing up your system badly) - if you installed one run:

   ```
   ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-###.##.run --uninstall
   ldconfig
   ```
2. Install the latest nvidia-3## from the official Ubuntu repositories.
3. Make sure you don't see anything odd while running the following command:

   ```
   ldconfig -p |grep libGL
   ```

   Look for some libGL libraries left by other packages, i.e. not provided by nvidia-3## Ubuntu package
4. Copy the libGL files to `~/.steam/bin` by running the following commands:

   ```
   cd ~/.steam/bin
   cp /usr/lib32/nvidia-3##/libGL* .
   ```

It's not a pretty solution, but it does work for me.

This workstation was originally Ubuntu 10.04. I kept on updating to each and every release. What also made it tricky for me, I had originally used the on-board ATI video card, so I had few references to fglrx libraries, which was probably causing the error about missing libatiuki.so.1 library.