# Trine 2 on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy 64-bit

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, 32-bit

Having bought Trine 2 on the Humble Indie Bundle, I can play the game on Ubuntu 13.04 after having installed the ia32-libs package.

This package has been deprecated in Ubuntu 13.10 and the game no longer works from this version of Ubuntu.

I have a done a fresh install and am unable to get the game working. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I was facing the same problem and found the answer in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package).

So, you have to install the missing 32-bit libraries in the following way:

```
sudo apt-get install package-name:i386
```

For me the required packages were:

```
libopenal1:i386
libportaudio2:i386
libglu1-mesa:i386
libvorbisfile3:i386
libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

I installed them step by step and checked the still missing libraries after each package by entering following commands in the Trine 2 install directory (the first one is enough only once):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib/lib32
ldd bin/trine2_linux_32bit | grep "not found"
ldd bin/trine2_linux_launcher_32bit | grep "not found"
```

If further not found libraries remain after installing these five packages, please check the above thread how to find out the package name of a library.