# Skype 4.2 with ubuntu 12.04 64bit not work fine

Tags: 12.04, skype, lenovo

Hi i'm ubuntu n00b that have some problems.
I have installed the last version of skype by apt-get.
When i start a videocall, skype crash after two/two and half minutes
I don't understand why it crash.
When i start skype in the terminal, it appear this message

> giovanni@giovanni-Lenovo-Z580:~$ skype
>
> ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be
> preloaded: ignored.

can someone help me?

Comment: Other information :i have a Lenovo z580 laptop

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the above message because you are starting SKYPE (and this is so far the only way to do it) with the command in a terminal:

```
PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

However, this command only works after installing the **ia32-libs** package that contains the *v4l1compat.so* file, which is possible using the following procedure:

There is a workaround using ia32-libs from a previous distribution (13.04). This has been tested with the release candidate of 13.10 and all is well and functional.

Install Synaptic from terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Launch synaptic and goto “settings > Repositories” click “other software > add”
    insert this line in the box:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
```

Click OK and close synaptic.
In terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

[For more details and a technical  explanation of the above see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package) and [here](http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-13-10) ]

Comment: If i add this repo and i do the command "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade", it download 543 mb of packages. It is normal?