# Canon LBP7110Cw doesn't print with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon

I installed the Linux driver for my Canon LBP7110Cw printer on two pc : one with 32bits ubuntu 12.04, the other with 64bits ubuntu 12.04.
Here is the download link : 
http://www.canon.fr/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/Laser/i-SENSYS_LBP7110Cw.aspx

The installation worked well.
The printer is recognized by each PC.
But when I print a test page or a document, nothing happens.
An error message appears :

1. **on 64bits pc:**

for test page

> "src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 633, err = -1¥nDEBUG: Wrote 1
>   pages..."

for document

> "src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 633, err = -1¥nError
>   Response:ReqNo=2, SeqNo=3,opvpErrorNo=-2"

1. **On 32bits pc**

for test page

> "src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 633, err = -1¥nDEBUG2:
>   prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.1 = 100"

for document

> "src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 633, err = -1¥nDEBUG2:
>   prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.1 = 100"

I need help please !
Ljdn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Canon-Japan, here is the solution.
The drivers only support English or Japanese OS linux language.
After changing French to English, it works for 32 bits and 64 bits.
Ljdn

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue (*err = -1¥nDEBUG: Wrote 1 pages...*) today after installing [Canon-provided 64-bit drivers](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/laser_printers/color_imageclass_lbp7110cw#DriversAndSoftware) for an LBP7110cw printer on an (x)ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr workstation. Readme file within the .gzipped directory containing the drivers warned to install *ia32-libs* and *libjpeg62:i386*; however, [ia32-libs are no longer present in ubuntu 12.04 and later versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package).

Installing the following libraries prior to (re)installing the 64-bit driver fixed the issue and enabled printing:

```
# sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libjpeg62:i386
```

Comment: Thanks. I installed lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libjpeg62:i386. Then I installed the 64-bit driver again. The same error appeared. Next, I installed ia32-libs. I installed the 64-bit driver again. The same error appeared. So I can't still print. Moreover, I have the same problem with my 32 bits pc.So I don't think it's a problem of 32 bits libraries.