# Problem With ia32-libs-raring.list when attempting to install software

Tags: apt, 15.04, 64-bit

When I tried to install `ia32-libs` on Ubuntu 15.04 it gives me this error:

```
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 (raring) is no longer supported. The `ia32-libs` package has been deprecated for some time. What is you actual end goal?

Comment: I'm not using ubuntu 13.04 i'm using Ubuntu Gnome 15

Comment: Delete the file. And there is no more `ia32-libs` package. You need to install the `i386` version of each library dependency separately, instead.

Comment: The file is on "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" I don't know how to delete it.

Comment: @dobey ah, my bad. I forgot the raring part. We don't usually close questions as duplicates unless the questions are the same/very similar (there's a reason it is called "*exact* duplicate" hehe). Since there are multiple problems here I added an answer. Thanks for the edit btw. Answered from mobile and forgot to include sudo.

Comment: With the following command, you will see some hex-codes. [Edit] your question and add the output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring* | od -A x -t x1z -v`

Answer (score 4):

Run the command:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list
```

That will clear the first two errors. As for installing `ia32-libs`, that package has been deprecated for a while now. Whatever instructions you are following are outdated. For more information see [What happened to the ia32-libs package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package)

Also, please upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10, 15.04 will become end of life next month. You will lose updates and support and upgrading will become harder.

Comment: Seth, +1....but what happened to the iguana? :)

Comment: @heemayl He'll be back after hats ;) I usually use this avatar around April Fools (old joke) but it fits hats better.

Comment: And why is `.list` an invalid extension? I have created a file with exact this name and I have no problem.