# How to run Diogenes app on modern Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, compatibility

I've been using Linux in general for several years, but I've never played with programming etc. My question is the following. I would like to install a x32bit program on my x64bit computer but I could't find any way around it (Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, Arch, Manjaro), at some point something just doesn't work. I'm referring to Diogenes tool (https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Diogenes/linux_install.php). As an ancient Greek teacher I use it extremely often but I manage to run it only into some Win. VBox and I try to avoid that, if possible.

Is it any way to make it x64bit compatible? And can be carried out, after following some instructions, by a non programmer?

**Edit**: I was about to delete the question, but I wanted to point out that the "Diogenes project" is, once again, alive and rewritten for modern software (thanks to Peter Heslin from Durham University). It can be found [here](https://d.iogen.es/d/) (open-source).

Comment: Didn't the instructions in the _Troubleshooting_ section in the link you shared work?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package

Comment: More importantly, see the _The Last Resort_ section of your link. It should let you use it.

Comment: @dobey has some Perl problems in the code when run directly because it's designed for **older** Perl versions - `Can't use 'defined(@array)' at /usr/local/diogenes/perl/CPAN/CGI.pm` for one when you follow those last resort statements, because that behavior has been deprecated in later Perl versions.  So unless someone modernizes the code, this won't work at all.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes. As I stated in my comment to the unhelpful answer, even if one got the extremely old xulrunner based front-end to run, it would still not work because of the code problems.

Comment: @dobey oops, I missed that, my bad.

Comment: You could create a chroot and run it directly with `schroot`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some of the comments on previously posted answers, and on the question above, the version of *Diogenes* that exists will not work on modern perl, and as you've noted, the 32-bit x86 only binary front-end based on xulrunner is problematic. So, to be helpful, I've went and created a slight fork of the code, and tweaked it slightly to run on modern perl, and use some more modern conventions (XDG config/runtime directories), as well as implemented a simple front-end based on QtWebEngine, that can run on any architecture.

You can grab a tarball from https://github.com/dobey/diogenes-ng/releases/tag/0.3.2.0.2 and install it, to see if it works for your needs. I'd suggest keeping the VM on hand, just in case something goes wrong, as I don't really know the code well, or how it's supposed to be used, so I haven't really tested it too extensively. If you find an issue, feel free to open one at https://github.com/dobey/diogenes-ng/issues and explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All this is deprecated now (Fall 2019). A new, official version of Diogenes (4.0) is now available. It's 64bit and works like a charm.
Adress : https://d.iogen.es/d/index.html