# how can I install a 32bit library on a 64bit system

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get 32 bit version of libraries on Ubuntu 64 bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27377/how-to-get-32-bit-version-of-libraries-on-ubuntu-64-bit)

I use winbind on 12.04 64bit, but some 32bit programs (like acroread) need the 32bit version of libnss_windbind (from the package libpam_winbind). How can I install the 32bit version of libpam_winbind on my 64bit system?

Answer (score 10):

Open a terminal and paste: `apt-get install ia32-libs`.

Comment: I already installed ia32-libs, but in 12.04 libpam_winbind is not anymore included in ia32-libs, that is my problem.

Comment: Just tried this in 13.10 and received: `Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate`

Comment: This library has been replaced with `lib32ncurses5`, `lib32bz2-1.0`, and `lib32z1`.