# running a 32 bit .bin file on 64 bit Kubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, multiarch

I am running a 64-bit version of Kubuntu 12.04. When trying to run a 32-bit .bin file I am getting the following error:

```
$ ./jdevstudio11121install.bin
./jdevstudio11121install.bin: No such file or directory
```

However when I run a file command I receive the following:

```
$ file jdevstudio11121install.bin 
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped
```

How do I run this file? Is it possible to run 32-bit executable on a 64-bit OS. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/20355/running-32-bit-app-under-64-bit-linux. The bottom line is run `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs -y` first and then try again.

Comment: @izx This question is substantially more specific than that one. It seems to me that this shouldn't be considered a duplicate of it, even if the answers are essentially the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type this in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

This will install most needed 32 bit libraries and hopefully you will be able to run the file.

Or if you prefer, you can install the `ia32-libs` package in the Software Center.