# Help: cannot install a gz package on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit

Tags: 12.10, vnc, executable, archive, vncviewer

I am a new Ubuntu user. I'm trying to install a package in a file called `VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-Linux-x86.gz`. I keep having problems.

The package is in my folder: `/home/Downloads/VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-Linux-x86.gz`

I tried:

```
owner@ubuntu:~$ cd ~/Downloads
owner@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz
[sudo] password for owner: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz'
```

I also tried:

```
owner@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I have followed `sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall` as explained on [this wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) and I am still quite lost in how to install this `gz` package. This package is needed to remotely control my school computer.

My Kernel is Linux-3.5.0-21 generic (x86-64)
Distribution Ubuntu 12.10
GNU C compiler version 4.7.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: Not a compressed tarball (.tar.gz, .tar.bz2)? Then `gunzip VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz`

Comment: Indeed, as @Christopher points out, this is *not* a duplicate of [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file), and the answers [by Christopher](http://askubuntu.com/a/232722/22949) and [by McNisse](http://askubuntu.com/a/232725/22949) are quite appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *gz* file is compressed with *gzip*, so just "un-gzip" a file with `gunzip`.
For the binary download at realvnc.com, as a regular user:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cd ~/bin
mv ~/Downloads/VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz .
gunzip VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz
chmod +x VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86
```

Then double-click it from a GUI file manager or start it from the command line:

```
~/bin/VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86
```

If there was no bin directory to start, then the PATH will get updated when you log out and in again. After this it's just

```
VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86
```

from any directory. You could rename the file, too, if you like, or make symbolic link:

```
cd ~/bin
ln -s VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86 vncv
```

Then call it with `vncv` or whichever name you pick for the symlink.

Comment: Hi. I really appreciate the help. But I run into some problems at the third step:owner@ubuntu:~$ mkdir -p ~/bin
owner@ubuntu:~$ cd ~/bin
owner@ubuntu:~/bin$ mv ~/Downloads/VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz
mv: missing destination file operand after `/home/owner/Downloads/VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
Am I missing some simple things?

Comment: @user116727 Is the command missing the "dot" at the end of the command? It's `mv source destination`, so the "dot" is the destination, referring to the current directory, ~/bin.

Comment: @user116727 They have a 64-bit binary download, too.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a really dumb question. I swear I put the file in the download folder. but when i re-run the code. it says owner@ubuntu:~/bin$ mv ~/Downloads/VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz .
mv: cannot stat `/home/owner/Downloads/VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz': No such file or directory
i'm really confused. i swear the folder is there...

Comment: @user116727 If it really is in /home/owner/Downloads, maybe tab completion could help with typos? mv /home/owner/Downloads/VNC[TAB]   /home/owner/bin. Or use a GUI file manager.

Answer (score 0):

The file that you have downloaded contains *x86* in the name. This gives a hint that it contains a 32-bit binary, you should be able to make in run by installing a 32-bit runtime. But one cannot be sure before the file is unpacked.

Hovewer, before I go in to how you unpack the file. Have you tried any of the vnc viewers that exist in the package manager? `xvnc4viewer`, `xtightvncviewer` and some more. Start the package manager and search for *vnc*.

Now, back to your file. Unpack it with gunzip.

```
gunzip VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86.gz
```

You should get a file named `VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86`. You need to make it executable and then start it:

```
chmod +x VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86
./VNC-Viewer-5.0.3-linux-x86
```

This might not work because you may not have 32-bit supporting libraries ("runtime") installed (or the archive contains something else). Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138454/running-a-32-bit-bin-file-on-64-bit-kubuntu).