# unable to load shared object wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: 12.04, shared-library, r

I have a linux server with x86_64.

I'm compiling an R code that needs to load a bibliblioteca. When I run this code it displays the following error has:

```
Error in dyn.load ("functions.so"):
Unable to load shared object 'functions.so':
functions.so': wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138454/running-a-32-bit-bin-file-on-64-bit-kubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got `functions.so` from, but the problem is that it is a 32-bit library, and you are trying to load it into a 64-bit process. You need a 64-bit version of the library, or presumably the 32-bit version of `R`.